# print.c is missing from lua 5.2, trying to build from source

Tags: windows, build, lua

I am trying to build Lua from source and when I look at http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ I basically see what I got in the source file, and I don't see `print.c`.

In my build.bat (I am doing this on Windows 7) I have this:

```
cl /MD /O2 /W3 /c /DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL *.c
del *.o
ren lua.obj lua.o
ren luac.obj luac.o
ren print.obj print.o
link /DLL /IMPLIB:lua5.2.lib /OUT:lua5.2.dll *.obj
link /OUT:lua.exe lua.o lua5.2.lib
lib /out:lua5.2-static.lib *.obj
link /OUT:luac.exe luac.o print.o lua5.2-static.lib
```

If I just remove all references to print.o will there be a problem with what I compile when I try to embed this in my game?

In lua 5.1, under compiler you will see `print.c`, so I wonder if I should not do 5.2.

http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/

**UPDATE**

So, what I did was change my build.bat and removed the print.obj, but I think the rename was useful in order to not include lua.obj and luac.obj in the .lib file, so I rename them and then rename them back.

```
cl /MD /O2 /W3 /c /DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL *.c
del *.o
ren lua.obj lua.o
ren luac.obj luac.o
link /DLL /IMPLIB:lua5.2.lib /OUT:lua5.2.dll *.obj
link /OUT:lua.exe lua.o lua5.2.lib
lib /out:lua5.2-static.lib *.obj
ren lua.o lua.obj
ren luac.o luac.obj
link /OUT:luac.exe luac.obj lua5.2-static.lib
```

Comment: There is no print.c in Lua 5.2.

Comment: More importantly, why would you expect to see such a file? Every "minor" version number of Lua represents a significant change in the language. Why would the file structure not change too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `print.c` in Lua 5.2, the only public function it defined is moved to `luac.c`. See [`PrintFunction()`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/luac.c.html#PrintFunction) now found in `luac.c`.

Also, it is not a good idea to rename `.obj` to `.o` in Windows. Use whatever object file name is preferred by your tool chain.

**Edit:** I now see the purpose of the renaming, and while it does work, I still think it is a bad practice.

The trick is that the `CL` command in your batch file is compiling every `.c` file in your current directory with identical options. As it happens, that isn't a problem, but it isn't a conventional way of doing this sort of thing.

Then, because a few of those files aren't actually part of the DLL you want to build, you rename those so that you can fit the rest on the `LINK` command line as a single wild card `*.obj`.

If you are going to use a batch file to build Lua yourself, then it would be better to list the `.obj` files that make up the DLL and each application on each relevant link line rather than depend on a wild card. As it is, if you had a build error in the CL command, you still build a DLL with *all the rest* of the objects, or worse, possibly with an out of date object for the file that didn't compile.

Then you might or might not successfully link lua.exe and luac.exe even though there were errors.

The right answer here is to use a build tool of some form to compile and link. Microsoft should have provided you NMake, it might have provided you their internal tool (used to drive builds of the Windows kernel and device drivers, I know it comes with the DDK tools but I think it is also in the Platform SDK and may be buried in VS) named BUILD, and there is always the option of adding a more broadly used build system such as [GNU Make](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm), CMAKE, or countless others.

If you insist on using the renaming trick because it is more expedient than learning to do it the right way right now, then please at least add some testing for the successful completion of each compile and link step with `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :EOF` commands to end the batch file after a failure, as shown below.

As I edited the batch file, I notice another potential issue. You built all the OBJ files with `/DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL`, but then make a static library and link luac.exe from it. I don't know offhand what features of the source text are modified by that definition, but it probably isn't wise to make a static library from OBJ files compiled with it instead of a DLL.

```
cl /MD /O2 /W3 /c /DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL *.c
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :EOF
del *.o
ren lua.obj lua.o
ren luac.obj luac.o
link /DLL /IMPLIB:lua5.2.lib /OUT:lua5.2.dll *.obj
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :EOF
link /OUT:lua.exe lua.o lua5.2.lib
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :EOF
cl /MD /O2 /W3 /c *.c
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :EOF
del *.o
ren lua.obj lua.o
ren luac.obj luac.o
lib /out:lua5.2-static.lib *.obj
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :EOF
ren lua.o lua.obj
ren luac.o luac.obj
link /OUT:luac.exe luac.obj lua5.2-static.lib
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you. According to a tutorial on compiling for Windows that was the suggestion, so that is what I was following.